# how to sklearn kFold with custom class strata?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I was reading this [article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-validation-for-imbalanced-classification/) on how to do proper KFold for a very imbalanced dataset.
At the last example, it shows how to split a dataset in 2 folds, 50/50 train/test. All very cool and interesting. I am however wondering how can I do a split where I can also control the class distribution in each fold, for example 50/50 class0/class1 (aka under/oversampling). So given the data below, say I would like 4 Folds, I am looking for the following outcome:

```
>Train: 0=8, 1=8, 
>Train: 0=8, 1=8, 
>Train: 0=8, 1=8, 
>Train: 0=8, 1=8,
```

Is there any way to achieve this with any of the `sklearn.model_selection` methods? I've looked for this everywhere with no luck. Could this be because this method should not be used with KFold?

```
# example of stratified train/test split with an imbalanced dataset
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# generate 2 class dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2, weights=[0.99, 0.01], flip_y=0, random_state=1)

# split into train/test sets with same class ratio
trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=2, stratify=y)

# summarize
train_0, train_1 = len(trainy[trainy==0]), len(trainy[trainy==1])
test_0, test_1 = len(testy[testy==0]), len(testy[testy==1])
print('>Train: 0=%d, 1=%d, Test: 0=%d, 1=%d' % (train_0, train_1, test_0, test_1))
```

```
>Train: 0=495, 1=5, Test: 0=495, 1=5
```

Answer (score 0):

If 50/50 distribution between classes is your objective, sklearn have [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) for that. It uses under sampling to ensure all classes have equal no of samples in each fold.

But if you want greater control, say you want the distribution to be 30/70, sklearn isn't enough, you will need [imbalance-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library for that. The [`RandomUnderSampler`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html) for example will allow you to precisely control the distribution, through the `sampling_strategy` parameter. In fact, if you're working with very imbalanced dataset in python, you probably should acquaint yourself with that library and its algorithms to some extent, not just `RandomUnderSampler`.

Comment: Ok, but how do you adjust the class split?

Comment: the doc page on [RandomUnderSampler](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html), in particular the part describing `sampling_strategy`  parameter describes it quite well, so I decided not to repeat that in this answer